# Why do pages load quickly on Safari on macOS, but not on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

For the last week or so loading the exact same URL on Chrome is practically impossible, whereas Safari loads the pages instantaneously. These are not cached pages, either.

Any thoughts on this?

iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2019)
macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G95)

Comment: What is the URL? - It might be a problem with that server/page and not Crome as such, or it might be a URL that offers something that Chrome uses but Safari doesn't, and that makes the difference.

Comment: It happens with both google.com and with tcc.instructure.com.

Comment: Does that also happen in a freshly created account?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific solution or answer for such a thing. First, Chrome is a memory hungry application. However, here are the basic reasons. For others, we have to know the details.

- Reason 1: Your Cache is Beyond Overworked
- Reason 2: Chrome is Outdated
- Reason 3: Flash is Always Enabled
- Reason 4: Overzealous Plugins/Extensions

Clear the cache, revmoe extensions and disable flash if needed.

But as I mentioned earlier, these are the primary workaround. Else, you can try to reinstall your Chrome.

Comment: I tried erasing the cache, but Chrome also got hung up on chrome://settings/clearBrowserData, so I'm guessing this is not a network issue, but a local app issue.

Comment: Have you try to uninstall Chrome and install it back again ?

Comment: I manually removed all Chrome files by following one of the instructions available online. After installing Chrome again the symptoms went away.